# Function nested inside an object property does not execute

Tags: javascript, object

I have a weird behavior on my arms :

I declare an object, properties shall execute in sequence, which they do, but in one there is a simple pass through nothing written in it happens.

Do I have a scope problem ?

Here is a code fragment where verteX is my object

```
stepsCalcul: function() {
  var test = 2;
  verteX.testCheck = test*2; //returns undefined
  alert('stuff') //alerts nothing
  console.log("logged stuff")//logs nothing
  verteX.mouseCoordinates();
  return true;
},
```

I sort a jsFiddle aswell

http://jsfiddle.net/AEWrK/3/

Thanks!

Comment: The problem in your fiddle is that you don't call the `init` method. Here's an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jamesallardice/AEWrK/4/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your fiddle, you're not calling the `init` function.

Replace `verteX.init;` with `verteX.init();`

Comment: I think I've been totally mislead by the mousemove event being launch, does object property calling jquery methods execute stand-alone-ly ?

Comment: from your fiddle, `verteX.mouseCoordinate` doesn't contain a function, but a jQuery object. Incidently you bound an handler to the "mousemove" event, while affectif the jQuery object to `mouseCoordinate`.

Comment: Remember, `verteX.init` is the function, `verteX.init()` is the result returned by the function. Functions are just objects, much like an int, or a string, you can pass them around, or invoke them.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I was wrongly thinking than an object property was a function by default.